# how to save a enum value from void method in java

Tags: java

In `golog()` `eLogType.ADMINACTIONLOG` is a enum,in this case i have given a string value,when `golog(eLogType.ADMINACTIONLOG)` is called,i could able to get the value,i need to save the value in other variable,how could that in java?

```
public static void golog(eLogType e) 
{
     String formattedString=null;
     switch (e) {
     case LOG:
            formattedString ="#LOG - "+currentDateandTime +" File:"+new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() +" Line:"+new                          
  Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();   
     break;
     case EXCEPTIONLOG:
formattedString ="#EXCEPTIONLOG - "+currentDateandTime +" File:"+new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() +
 " Line:"+new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();                     
      break;

    }                                                  
}
```

Comment: hi,I have a void method golog in this method i have switch case,i could able to get the values from switch case by calling method golog(case1) like that,but i need to display this value along with other values from a function together,i need to save the value in golog(case1) in other variable,that is what i want to do..

Answer (score 1):

You can take the value in the following way:

- `golog(eLogType.ADMINACTIONLOG.toString())` **or**
- `golog(eLogType.ADMINACTIONLOG.name())`

e.g. having a method :

```
private void myMethod(eLogType type) {
    switch (type) {
    case ADMINACTIONLOG: {
        String asString = type.name();
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes in need to save that value in string

Comment: Hi, i couldnt able to do that since i am defining golog as public static void golog( eLogType e),i am passing  eLogType to golog method

Comment: You just have to change the `type` parameter name to `e`.

Comment: i have changed but is is showing error as string variable are not applicable since elogType is a enum.

Comment: That's strange. For me everything compiles (using JDK7). Can you update the question with the full code you have right now ?